# How to call Passport Authenticate function from sails action2

Tags: sails.js, passport.js, passport-jwt

I am using sails js v1.0. I am not getting way to how I call passport's authenticate function. Since req, res and next is not there in sails new controller type (action2).

I want to use a passport JWT based auth in sails js v1 app.

```js
 fn: async function (inputs, exits) {
          passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false}, (err, user, info) => {
        })(inputs, exits);
    }
```

my config/passport.js looks like

```js
passport.use('jwt', new JWTStrategy(opts, (jwtPayload, done) => {
  //find the user in db if needed. This functionality may be omitted if you store everything you'll need in JWT payload.
  User.findOne({email: jwtPayload.email}).then(async (err, user) => {

    if (err) {
      return done(err, false);
    }

    if (!user) {
      return done(null, false, {message: 'Incorrect email.'});
    }

    const validate = await sails.helpers.checkPassword(inputs.password, userRecord.password);

    if(!validate) return done(null, false, { message : 'Wrong Password'});

    return done(null, user, { message : 'Logged in Successfully Hola'});

  }).catch(err => {
    return done(err);
  })
}));
```

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: yes i found that.
you can use this.req to sovle this problem

Comment: Could you please post your solution as an answer to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Sails.js document](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/actions-and-controllers#?actions-2), the two ways are simply mentioned to access `req` object.

1. Using `this.req`

I used `this.req` and `this.res` for `passport.authenticate()` function, and it worked.
As you know, `req.login()` is required for login, but in my case, `this.req` didn't have `login()` function derived by passport. So, I failed to use it in this way.

2. Using `env` as the 3rd parameter.

In the document, this method is an alternative, but, in my case, both are different.
I can access `env.req.login()`.

So I think using `env` as the 3rd parameter is better then `this.req`.

```js
fn: async function (inputs, exits, env) {
  passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }, (err, user, info) => {

    // Write your codes. The below is an example.

    if (err || !user) return exits.unauthorized();

    env.req.login(user, function (err) {
      if (err) exits.error(err);

      return exits.success(user);
    });


  })(env.req, env.res);
}
```